# Replace strings in a file with another matching string from another file

Tags: bash, text-processing

I have a `file1` in which the 2nd last column is a code for first column, for example, *Rv0002* has two codes *S*, and *L*:

```
Rv0001 -       hypothetical protein Rv0019c    T       Signal_transduction_mechanisms
Rv0002  -       hypothetical protein Rv0030     S       Function_unknown
Rv0002 pknA    TRANSMEMBRANE SERINE (STPK A)        L       recombination_and_repair
```

There is another `file2` which has all unique *Rv** 's in first column:

```
Rv0001  -0.581372258    -0.147459774    0.548735372 1.001137114
Rv0002  -1.555384307    0.386044242 0.046125098 -0.06681665
```

I would like to have a third file `output` which is the same as `file2` except each *Rv**  is replaced with its code(s). For example, in above example, `output` will look like:

```
T   -0.581372258    -0.147459774    0.548735372 1.001137114
S   -1.555384307    0.386044242 0.046125098 -0.06681665
L   -1.555384307    0.386044242 0.046125098 -0.06681665
```

This is the closes I've got, but it is not working.

```
#!/bin/bash
while read p; do

  gene=$( awk '{print $1}' )
  grep "$gene" $2 | while read -r line ; do
    function_code=$( awk '{print $(NF-1)}' )
    new_row=$(echo $line | sed -e 's/$gen/$function_code/g' )
    echo $new_row >> output
  done

done < $1
```

My files have around ten thousand lines if that matters.

Comment: Just a question - are the codes in file 1 always one letter ?

Comment: @Sergiy Kolodyazhnyy yes, they are.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all your `file1` does not have any specific delimiter, second you have same keys with different values like `"Rv0002 S"` and `"Rv0002 L"`.

As your desired  output shows, I consider all lines are sorted and you just want to join these two file together.

Here is what I would do:

```
sed -r "s/(^Rv[0-9]+\s).*(\s+[A-Z]\s+).*/\1\2/" file1 > list1
```

It will create a list of keys for me like:

```
$ cat list1
Rv0001  T       
Rv0002  S       
Rv0002  L
```

After all I'll join them and cut my desired fields:

```
$ join list1 file2 | cut -f2- -d' '
T  -0.581372258 -0.147459774 0.548735372 1.001137114
S  -1.555384307 0.386044242 0.046125098 -0.06681665
L  -1.555384307 0.386044242 0.046125098 -0.06681665
```

Comment: Ooops! my mistake, the first column in both `file1` and `file2` are the same, I just updated it. But, as you mentioned, values are not unique, (maybe "key,value" is a misnomer here)

Comment: Updated my answer ;)

Comment: what if there is some `Rv000x` which exists in `file1` but not in `file2` ? lol, sorry I didn't know this until I got a `join: myFile:93: is not sorted: Rv0078 K` error now (I `sort`ed them).

Comment: If there was a row in `file1` which is not in `file2` it ignores that line and doesn't complain about it.  try `join  --nocheck-order list1 file2`.

Comment: You can do all with a single chain of pipes: `sed -r 's/(^Rv[0-9]+\s).*(\s+[A-Z]\s+).*/\1\2/' file1 | join - file2 | cut -f2- -d' '`